Segmentation fault (core dumped) in reading a binary file, memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory
I am trying to debug a piece of code that reads binary files I created. It seems that when the number of elements to read is higher than a certain treshold, the script I wrote fails.
The file contains is structured as follow: for each time t it has the time t then N particles struct (each containing some info about that particle, position, speed and so on, probably not relevant).
File is generated with
int update_binary_file(const char *name, particle *P, parameters par, double *time)
{

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(name, "a+");

    if (!file)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(time, sizeof(double), 1, file);
    fwrite(P, sizeof(particle), par.N, file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

Where particle is a struct defined like this:
typedef struct
{
    double x, y, z;    // position
    double vx, vy, vz; // velocity
    double wx, wy, wz; // acceleration
    int next_inbox;

} particle;

Parameters is another struct but is not relevant here, I use it just to pass the par.N value (number of particle in the system).
Finally I read the file as follow:
void read_binaryfile(parameters par, char *filename, double *x, double *y, double *z, double *vx, double *vy, double *vz, double *wx, double *wy, double *wz, double *t)
{
    int dump;
    
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("ERROR: invalid file %s\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    else
    {   
        for (int line = 0; line < par.Nsnap; line++)
        {
            if (fread(&t[line], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                break;
            printf("%f\n", t[line]);
            for(int n = 0; n < par.N; n++){
                int lin_index = linear_index(n, line);
                if (fread(&x[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double)){
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&y[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&z[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&vx[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&vy[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&vz[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&wx[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&wy[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&wz[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&dump, 1, sizeof(int), file) != sizeof(int))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&dump, 1, sizeof(int), file) != sizeof(int))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
 
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}


It basically reads all the particle struct values one by one, instead of reading the struct itself (because is more practical).
The script works well for small files and I can read them with Python. When the total number of elements in the file is higher, I get segmentation fault error. More specifically in gdb:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:418
418 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:418
#1  0x00007ffff788b423 in __GI__IO_file_xsgetn (fp=0x55555556cea0, data=<optimized out>, n=8) at ./libio/fileops.c:1295
#2  0x00007ffff787fba9 in __GI__IO_fread (buf=0x7ffdf7ad6af8, size=1, count=8, fp=0x55555556cea0) at ./libio/iofread.c:38
#3  0x00005555555559ae in read_binaryfile (par=..., 
    filename=0x7fffffffe127 "snap/m0.68_J18.00_g80.00_n1.00_T7.60_r1.00_v2.00/rho4.0_L4_N256_dt0.010_correlations_ICrand_dtsave0.05_t10.00.bin", x=0x7ffff7e37010, y=0x7ffff7b9d010, z=0x7ffff7b3a010, vx=0x7ffff7ad7010, vy=0x7ffff7a74010, 
    vz=0x7ffff779d010, wx=0x7ffff773a010, wy=0x7ffff76d7010, wz=0x7ffff7674010, t=0x55555556beb0)
    at spacetime_correlations.c:151
#4  0x000055555555602a in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdd28) at spacetime_correlations.c:226

All the arrays x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,wx,wy,wz are defined as:
    double *x = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));

and it seems to me that I never exceed their maximum dimension while assigning them their values read from the file with fread(&vz[lin_index], etc...).
I do not know where the problem comes from, usually Segmentation fault means a problem in the memory but here the indices seems all good to me.
UPDATE 1.
Minimal code to produce output file called N100.bin.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct
{
    double x, y, z;    // position
    double vx, vy, vz; // velocity
    double wx, wy, wz; // acceleration
    int next_inbox;

} particle;


int update_binary_file(const char *name, particle *P, int N, double *time)
{

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(name, "a+");

    if (!file)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(time, sizeof(double), 1, file);
    fwrite(P, sizeof(particle), N, file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int N = 100;
    particle *P = (particle *)calloc(N, sizeof(particle));
    int Nsteps = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        P[i].x = 1;
        P[i].y = 1;
        P[i].z = 1;
        P[i].vx = 1;
        P[i].vy = 1;
        P[i].vz = 1;
        P[i].wx = 1;
        P[i].wy = 1;
        P[i].wz = 1;
        P[i].next_inbox = 1;
    }
    double time;

    for (int i = 0; i < Nsteps; i++)
    {
        time = i*0.1;
        update_binary_file("N100.bin", P, N, &time);
    }
    
    
}   

Minimal code to read the N100.bin file generated.
// gcc spacetime_correlations.c -o spacetime_correlations -lm -O3

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define linear_index(n, t) ((n) + (t) * par.N )

    typedef struct
{
    int N, Nsnap, L;
} parameters;

typedef struct
{
    double x, y, z;    // position
    double vx, vy, vz; // velocity
    double wx, wy, wz; // acceleration
    int next_inbox;

} particle;


void read_binaryfile(parameters par, char *filename, double *x, double *y, double *z, double *vx, double *vy, double *vz, double *wx, double *wy, double *wz, double *t)
{
    int dump;
    
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("ERROR: invalid file %s\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    else
    {   
        for (int line = 0; line < par.Nsnap; line++)
        {
            if (fread(&t[line], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                break;
            printf("%f\n", t[line]);
            for(int n = 0; n < par.N; n++){
                int lin_index = linear_index(n, line);
                if (fread(&x[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double)){
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&y[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&z[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&vx[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&vy[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&vz[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&wx[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&wy[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&wz[lin_index], 1, sizeof(double), file) != sizeof(double))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&dump, 1, sizeof(int), file) != sizeof(int))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (fread(&dump, 1, sizeof(int), file) != sizeof(int))
                {
                    printf("ERROR reading file!\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
 
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    // Provide filename from command line
    char *filename = argv[1], *dump;

    parameters par;

    double *time = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *C_t = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vx = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vy = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vz = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *x = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *y = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *z = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
 

    // Count number of "lines" (e.g. the number of particles arrays at different time)
    int count = 0;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    while(fgetc(file) != EOF)
    {
        count++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    // Get number of particles from file name
    sscanf(filename,"N%d", &par.N);
    par.Nsnap = count/(sizeof(particle)*par.N+sizeof(double));

    printf("%d\n", par.N);

    read_binaryfile(par, filename, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, wx, wy, wz, time);

    free(time);
    free(C_t);
    free(Vx);
    free(Vy);
    free(Vz);
    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(z);
    free(vx);
    free(vy);
    free(vz);
    free(wx);
    free(wy);
    free(wz);
    free(delta_vx);
    free(delta_vy);
    free(delta_vz);

    return 1;
}

Notice that if I change in the first script Nsteps to a lower value, than I do not have the segmentation fault error while using the second script.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Are the parameters initialized in the same way all the time? Are par.N and par.Nsnap always the same when writing and reading the file? When you provide the MRE requested ba Eric Postpischil, please also include some test data you use for create the file.

yes, par.N is the same and known. par.Nsnap is simply the number of "lines" of the binary file.
How should I add files to the question?

You could add sample code that uses update_binary_file to create the file.

How do you know, how many "lines" are stored in the file before opening it? Why do you use a struct when you write the file but separate values for reading? When writing a struct, there might be some padding bytes that would need to be taken care of when reading single values.

@Gerhardh I guess that is why there are two calls to fread of size sizeof(int) at the end. The last one would be for padding. But this is all rather non-portable.

@IanAbbott You're right. That might fix it but as you mentioned, portability left the room...

Yes, that is not very smart indeed. It would have been better to read as a struct (I was about to change it as the next debugging step). Anyway, I don't think that is the problem here.
About portability I always wrote just for myself, so I never had to think about it; sorry about that!

In "spacetime_correlations.c" main(), par is uninitialized before use, leading to UB.

You should allocate those buffers after filling in par so that par.N and par.Nsnap are valid in the calculations to set the size of the buffers. I don't know if your real code has the same problem as this minimal reproducible example.

Didn't your compiler show any warning about using unitialized variable par? If not, you need to increase warning level. For gcc use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic.

@Gerhardh
Indeed, my compiler did not complain... Thank you for the precious suggestion! Will follow :)

The buffer sizes depend on an uninitialized variable leading to undefined behavior.
    parameters par;

    double *time = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *C_t = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vx = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vy = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vz = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *x = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *y = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *z = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));

Move those buffer allocations to a point where par.N and par.Nsnap are valid:
    // Get number of particles from file name
    sscanf(filename,"N%d", &par.N);
    par.Nsnap = count/(sizeof(particle)*par.N+sizeof(double));

    printf("%d\n", par.N);

    double *time = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *C_t = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vx = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vy = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *Vz = (double *)calloc(par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *x = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *y = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *z = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *vz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *wz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vx = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vy = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));
    double *delta_vz = (double *)calloc(par.N * par.Nsnap, sizeof(double));

    read_binaryfile(par, filename, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, wx, wy, wz, time);


Oh my, such a silly mistake! Can't believe I did not spot it :(
Anyway thank you and thanks also @Gerhardh, I will implement more strict warning level!
